# Accessing an object's uid Firebase

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In Firebase we can create a new object like so:

```
Firebase *postRef = [ref childByAppendingPath: @"posts"];
NSDictionary *post1 = @{
    @"author": @"gracehop",
    @"title": @"Announcing COBOL, a New Programming Language"
};
Firebase *post1Ref = [postRef childByAutoId];
[post1Ref setValue: post1];
```

And this new post might be saved at a URL like: `http://app.firebaseIO.com/posts/$postuid`

Later on when a user is in some `UIViewController` viewing a post, we might want to post a comment. In order to post a comment, however, we need access to the post's uid. It seems that the only way this would be possible is if we save the uid to our post object?

Basically, in general is it best practice to store an object's uid inside of it?

Comment: In general the uid in Firebase would refer the the users uid, as obtained from authData.uid. In this case are you asking if you should store a users uid (perhaps the uid of the user that posted it) as a child of post1Ref?

Comment: @Jay I'm referring to `uid` more generally as unique identifier.

Comment: Don't :-)   It really will cause confusion unless you are referring specifically to the authData.uid assigned via Firebase authentication methods. The unique identifier would called be the parent node or possibly the key. The answer in this case is no, you do not need to also store the unique identifier (key) inside the node as it can always be obtained from the snapshot.key. Of course the value is snapshot.value as well. There may be some special case where it may need to be stored inside the node but not generally.

Comment: Sounds like a great answer @Jay!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in this case is no, you do not need to also store the unique identifier (key) inside the node as it can always be obtained from snapshot.key.

The value of the key:value pair is obtained from snapshot.value.

There may be some special case where the key may need to be stored inside the node but not generally.

Example to print each key and value from a users node

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Kirk"
  uid_1
    name: "Spock"
```

and the code

```
let ref = Firebase(url:"https://your-app.firebaseio.com/users")
ref.queryOrderedByChild("name").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    print("The key: \(snapshot.key)") //the key
    print("The Value: \(snapshot.value)") //all the values for this key
    let specificValue = snapshot.value["name"] as! NSString
    print("Specific value: \(specificValue)") //a specific value
})
```

Note that in this case each users node has a uid_x as it's key. This unique identifier is obtained from authData.uid. when the user is created. Traditionally, node keys in other nodes would be created by childByAutoId ( or push() for non iOS )

And to your question; depending on use, it's often convenient to store firebase snapshot data in a dictionary, and store those dictionaries (or classes) in an array as a tableView dataSource. The array maintains the order.